$V(X^\top AX)=tr(\Sigma A\Sigma A) + tr(\Sigma A\Sigma A^\top)$
Let $X$ be an $n$-dimensional random vector with $E[X]=0$ and $E[XX^\top] = \Sigma$, and let $A$ be a matrix in $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$.
A paper I'm reading claims that $V(X^\top A X)=tr(\Sigma A\Sigma A) + tr(\Sigma A\Sigma A^\top)$.
I was able to compute
$E[X^TAX] = E[tr(X^\top AX)]=E[tr(AXX^\top)]=tr(A\Sigma)$.
Next, I have to compute $E[(X^TAX)^2] = E[X^TAXX^TAX]$, but the trace trick that I've used previously does not seem to be enough...

Suppose that $X$ follows a centered $n$-variate t-distibution with $\nu>4$ degrees of freedom and symmetric scale matrix $\Sigma$. Let $A = \frac{1}{n}\Sigma^{-1}$. Then $$\operatorname{Var}[X^\top AX] = \frac{2\nu\cdot(n + \nu - 2)}{n\cdot(\nu-2)^2\cdot(\nu-4)}$$ as this quadratic form of t-distributed random variables is F-distributed. However, the formula in question yields $$\operatorname{tr}(\Sigma A\Sigma A) + \operatorname{tr}(\Sigma A\Sigma A^\top) = 2\operatorname{tr}(\Sigma A\Sigma A) = \frac 2n.$$ Clearly, both expressions are not euqal in general.

I believe that a variation of this statement holds if you assume that  $X$ follows a centered normal distribution with variance-covariance matrix $\Sigma$: $$\operatorname{Var}[X^\top A X] = 2\operatorname{tr}(\Sigma \tilde A\Sigma \tilde A)$$ with $\tilde A = \frac 12(A+A^\top)$; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form_(statistics)#Variance_in_the_Gaussian_case and the references there.
To me it seems like the trace of ${\color{red}2}\Sigma{\color{red}A}\Sigma\tilde A$ was falsely computed instead of the correct trace of $\Sigma\tilde A\Sigma\tilde A$ for non-symmetric $A$. Since if $A$ is symmetric (and $X$ is assumed to be normal), the formula holds.
